# How can I implement a calculation of trading fees into my TradingView strategy so i can tell the sell alerts to only fire when > fees and in profit

Tags: pine-script

had a really weird thought and wondered if it was possible because I can't put it together in my head...

I want to run some of my strategies on Binance 5m charts, they perform well on 15m but on 5m the average trade is smaller, resulting in any profit getting sucked up by fees in a majority of the trades.

I use BNB to pay my fees in Binance so I have the following settings on my strategy via TV:
Spot trading commission - 0.15%
Futures commission - 0.054%

Is there a way I can tell my sell alerts to only sell when my strategy parameters are hit, it's made enough to cover the fees AND is in profit?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an if condition?

Comment: Sure, you just need to add this into account when calculating your take profit level.